# How do I order tickets by ticket name and ticket number in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I have a JIRA project AAA and lots of tickets like AAA1, AAA2, AAA3

I'd like to search the tickets ordered by the name and ticket number, so it shows like this:

```
AAA1
AAA2
AAA3
```

what key word I should use for the filter?

I tried using 'order by Created', most of the tickets are displayed in order, but the one moved from other project is not in order because in the other project, it was created earlier.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In a JQL query, end the query with :

`ORDER BY key`

Comment: thanks Laurent Jalbert Simard, at first I thought I should use something as key, then I realize I should use 'key' .

Comment: For the future reference of others, yes, the key to sort by issue ID is literally called `Key`.  Typing that works in the UI as well.

Comment: `ORDER BY Summary DESC` worked for me to order by the ticket title.

Comment: That's called intuitive interface - question viewed more than 14k times.

Comment: @Pavel_K Indeed.